# why application spring boot deployed in wtpwebapps of eclipse, not in the tomcat work directory

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

I am sure it may be obvious to some but I cannot undestand why my application is deployed in

```
.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\
```

of eclipse, not in the traditional work directory of tomcat.

Is this normal ?
How can I change to make it deploy in the work directory ?

I am using tomcat 8, STS with spring-boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's where the Web Tools Platform deploys its apps when Tomcat is managed from inside Eclipse.

In the Servers view of Eclipse you will have your Tomcat instance. You can double click on this to edit it. There is a section called Server Locations, where the Server Path box has the path you have identified. There are also radio buttons for changing the configuration, though for some reason my copy of Eclipse always greys these out.

Comment: Maybe it is because - *Server must be published with no modules present to make changes.*.